# WPF: cannot access ComboBox's TextBox with FindName

Tags: wpf, combobox, textbox, null

I saw that I can access the templated parts of a `ComboBox` (the `TextBox`, `PopUp` and `Button`) via the `FindName` method.

The `TextBox` should be accessible by using `cb.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox")`, however, this always returns `null` for me.

As per melya's suggestion, I have tried using `cb.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cb);` instead -- this works on a simple test app, but not my own.

The difference, perhaps, is that I'm trying to do this before the `ComboBox` is loaded or initialised (I'm developing an `Attached Property` that adds functionality to `TextBoxes/ComboBoxes`).

`cb.ItemTemplate` shows as `null`.

Unfortunately, the obvious solution of trying `cb.ApplyTemplate()` returns `false` and doesn't do anything.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Did you try to make your own control which derives from `ComboBox` and  there create `TextBox textBox;` and initialize it in constructor: 
`textBox = this.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this) as TextBox;` ?

Comment: I've been trying to avoid derived controls by adding functionality via attached properties, but it seems that by doing this the associated Dependecy Property's property changed callback is called before the control's template is built. I'm wondering if there's a sneaky way around this along the lines of creating a new TextBox and attaching them to the ComboBox later...

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party here, but thought I'd answer in case anyone else ends up here, like I did.

In my case, I was working on a custom ComboBox control.  I followed other suggestions to handle this in the Loaded event, but (like the OP), kept getting a null return.  Eventually, I figured out that Loaded was too early.  My control was displayed on a tab, which was not initially visible.

Instead, overriding OnApplyTemplate was a better fit for me, since this comes after the Loaded event (when the template becomes available).   The code I used was as follows:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    var textBox = Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this) as TextBox;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
cb.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cb);
```

Comment: EDIT - ah, I think I may have discovered a difference, editing question to clarify