# Can't get ref to the TextBox in the CustomControl that is inherited form ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Here is example of code where I try to get a `TextBox` using `Template.FindName`, but as result I get `null`.

```
public class MeasureComboBox : ComboBox
{
    #region FIELDS
    /// <summary>
    /// TextBox that bilongs to ComboBox control. 
    /// </summary>
    private TextBox TextBox;
    #endregion

    static MeasureComboBox()
    {
    }

    public MeasureComboBox()
    {

    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        // Why this.TextBox is equal to null here?
        this.TextBox = this.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this) as TextBox;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Parser.Controls.OlxUrlCarMaxPriceParameters"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Parser.Controls"
             xmlns:w="clr-namespace:Parser.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <w:MeasureComboBox/> // Here is my custom control
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266689/wpf-cannot-access-comboboxs-textbox-with-findname) with similar problem of `null` value. But as you can see from my code those answers doesn't work for me.

**How to get ref to the TextBox control?** Why it doesn't work?

Comment: You should add the basic structure of the XAML to the question to make it easier to reproduce; just the relationship between the control, template and textbox. Maybe a few years ago I'd have known the answer off the top of my head but now I'd have to work on it to see what's going on and try to remember :)

Comment: @AlexPaven Added XAML to my question. I simplified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I thought your combo box was customized with a custom template; if you want to get the textbox that's provided as part of the default combo box template, you must make sure that the IsEditable property is set to true, otherwise the textbox is not created. So:

```
<StackPanel>
    <w:MeasureComboBox IsEditable="True" /> // Here is my custom control
</StackPanel>
```